# want to display zero when entered something in PL SQL

Tags: plsql

hi guys I am looking for a query that I want to display M0321 when I entered M321

for eg: if I entered M321 and I want to display it as M0321

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `select case when x = 'M321' then 'M0321' else x end from ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use LPAD to add 0 before your number. here is my solution:

```
select SUBSTR('M321',1,1) || LPAD(SUBSTR('M321',2),4,'0') from dual
```